# Location of Linux OS syslogs

Tags: linux, logging, operating-system, syslog

Can someone help me in understanding, what factors do decide whether OS syslogs are stored in /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages?

Comment: Seems you haven't got to `journalctl` yet. :-)

Comment: @oakad I am familiar with journald. I was curious about /var/log/messages and /var/log/syslog so asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of whether logs go to /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages is dependant on distribution type.

RPM based systems such as CentOS and RedHat use /var/log/messages and Debian based systems such as Ubuntu use /var/log/syslog.

Comment: Thanks for the info Raman!
So, is it so that now we have replaced the /var/log/messages with journald?

Comment: journald is part of systemd. Log filing is not persistent unless enabled though. By doing this, logging will be written to /var/log/journal. /var/log/messages and /var/log/rsyslog is written to by rsyslog and is persistent by default. Both can be run in parallel if required but journald is used to resolve any issues with log rotating associated with rsyslog